# How do I take all the garbage out of file names using a list of said garbage?

Tags: python

I have a folder full of media. These media files are very messy, they have a dozen or so different parts of their filenames  that either need to be taken out or replaced with spaces instead.

I thought that maybe I could make a list of those items and then reference that list in the `os.rename` but I am unsure how to do this.

```
def clean_names():
    path = (main_directory)
    filenames = os.listdir(path)
    for filename in filenames:
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, filename.replace('.', '')))
```

Where it says: `filename.replace('.', '')))` I would like to put an array or list of different items that I would like replaced instead of just the '.'    This also brings me to another issue of splitting the filename so I do not bother the extension.

Comment: You might be able to use the string.translate() function if you can create a "map" from garbage-in to your requested. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate

Comment: Regarding splitting the filename from its extension: `os.path.splitext()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach here would be to use [regexes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to match with multiple different patterns. It is hard to say what that regex would be without seeing some of the filenames.

Something along the lines of

```
  for filename in filenames:
        os.rename(
            os.path.join(path, filename),
            os.path.join(path, filename.replace(r'(\s+|\.|#+|....', '')))
```

This will replace any match with just empty string. 
Or if you wanted to use a list of values you could build it up with something like:

```
unwanted_values = [ "\.", "-", ... ]
regex = r'({0})'.format('|'.join(unwanted_values))
filename.replace(regex, "")
```

Comment: I havn't used regex before but this does seem to be the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use regex for replacing multiple characters in a string with the same replacement string cleanly.

```
import re

def clean_names():
    path = (main_directory)
    filenames = os.listdir(path)
    for filename in filenames:
        new_file = re.sub('\,|\-|1|2', '', filename)
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, new_file))
```

An explanation of the regular expression:
The pipe character '|' which separates different values translates to 'or'. The slash character escapes a character so that it is interpreted as the character itself, and not for it's meaning in regex.

The above would create a variable "new_file" that equals filename with any commas, dashes, or the numbers 1 or 2 replaced with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

another solution using regex assuming you have a list of unwanted strings to remove

```
import re
import os

path = (main_directory)
filenames = os.listdir(path)

values_to_replace=['list','of','unwanted','strings']

for filename in filenames:
    new_filename=re.sub('|'.join(values_to_replace),'',filename)
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, new_filename))
```